# How to map ValueInjecter using Json Object?

Tags: c#, json, valueinjecter

If I have Json object that I want to map to a concrete object, how would I do that?

```
  public class Student
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }  
    }

  class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var o = new JObject {{"Name", "Jim"}};
            Student student = new Student();


            student.InjectFrom(o);
        }
    }
```

this results in null. When I expected "Jim" to be set.

Comment: IIRC, `ValueInjecter` is designed to be used with 2 concrete typed instances. In your example, I doubt `ValueInjecter` can infer the properties from the JSON object.

Comment: JObject implements an `IDictionary` that's why you can have some kind of dynamic properties but ValueInjecter is design to map property with the same name, it will not look into the JOject Dictionary

Comment: How can I get around that? The Json key has the same name as you can see from my example.

Comment: you need to create a custom Injection by inheriting `KnownSourceInjection<JObject>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you're using [json.net](/questions/tagged/json.net) anyway, you can populate an object directly from JSON using [`JsonConvert.PopulateObject()`](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/M_Newtonsoft_Json_JsonConvert_PopulateObject.htm):

```
JsonConvert.PopulateObject(json, student);
```

Or if you prefer you can add some extensions methods:

```
public static class JsonExtensions
{
    public static void PopulateFromJson<T>(this T target, string json) where T : class
    {
        if (target == null || json == null)
            throw new ArgumentException();
        JsonConvert.PopulateObject(json, target);
    }

    public static void PopulateFromJson<T>(this T target, JToken json) where T : class
    {
        if (target == null || json == null)
            throw new ArgumentException();
        using (var reader = json.CreateReader())
            JsonSerializer.CreateDefault().Populate(reader, target);
    }
}
```

And do

```
        var o = new JObject { { "Name", "Jim" } };
        Student student = new Student();
        student.PopulateFromJson(o);
```